# javascript count html tag pattern on page load: "</b> <li>" (with space in between)

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to create a java script function that on page load counts amount of times this pattern appears in html code? `"</b> <li>"`(with one space in the middle between the `</b> and <li>` ) Would it be a dom element?

Thanks

Comment: Whatever you want to do you're doing it wrong :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
document.body.innerHTML.match(/<\/b>\s<li>/g).length
```

***Edit:*** as @Laas' answer hints, the solution above does not handle `0` nicely because `match` returns `null` rather than `[]`. To fix that, use his answer, or this (which is equivalent):

```
function countPattern()
{
    var matches = document.body.innerHTML.match(/<\/b>\s<li>/g);
    return matches ? matches.length : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the whole HTML and count regexp matches:

```
(m = (document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML).match(/<\/b> <li>/g)) ? m.length : 0
```

This would return count or 0 if none found.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that would be something like this:

```
function countHtml(fragment) {
  return document.body.innerHTML.match(new RegExp(fragment, 'g')).length;
}
```

Comment: That will require users of that function to properly escape the characters in `fragment`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript